# how to do a self-join

Tags: sql, nested

I have the following table with 3 columns, this is just a sample (not a real one)

```
Number Decription Value
1 Green 100
1 Yellow 101
1 Blue 102
2 Chair 200
2 Table 101
2 Green 150
3 Car 200
3 plane 205
3 green 105
```

My first query is to find any record or row which contain value "101" No problemo in this scenario I find 2 records [1, Yellow,101] and [2, table, 101] and all the records with number 3 and the rest are ignored just perfect. Now I need to select other records based on the RESULT of the FIRST query, the number 1 and 2 are the true results. So from column [number] in this case I found [1 and 2], I want to search and add the value of any description = [green]. Still ignoring [3] which has NO [101] value.

The ideal result I want to display is

```
[1, yellow, 101] and Green is 100
[2, table, 101] and Green is 150
```

I have got a headache to get it work so far NO good result. If anyone has a any idea how to make the script for this case please let me know. I hope the questions is clear.

P.S the content of the table is fake just to get an impression what is about and fyi it's SQL + PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select 
  concat('[', concat_ws(', ', s1.number, s1.description, s1.value), '] and ', s2.description, ' is ', s2.value)
from 
  sample s1
inner join 
  sample s2 on s2.number = s1.number
where 
  s1.value = 101 and 
  s2.description = 'Green'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f0a/1/0)

Comment: I have only one table and I see t1 and t2 my table is called [sample] so I have to replace both or just t1's with sample? c

Comment: _t1_ and _t2_ are aliases for the **same** table (_test_ in my example). You have to replace both occurrences of _test_ with _sample_.

Comment: [Other question about self joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886824/self-joining-a-table)

Comment: Sorry I am bit confused with this aliases concept.. I checked mysql documentation about alias I get even confused. I tried to apply [sample] to [t1] and [t2] I get error [Not unique table/alias: 'sample'] I know I ma messing up with the script now :(  I am going to check that tomorrow morning Thx a million for you help

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it uses your tablename (_sample_).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I think this is what you are trying to do.

edit.  Are you trying to only get the "Green"?

```
SELECT * from table WHERE table.Number IN (
    SELECT Number FROM table WHERE table.Value = 101
) AND table.Description = "Green";
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it comes with the following result: Name: 101 desc: Yellow number: 1
Name: 102 desc: Blue number: 1
Name: 200 desc: Chair number: 2
Name: 101 desc: Table number: 2
Name: 150 desc: Green number: 2

Comment: there is one filter based on 101 and after that a second filter which has to use the number column to retrieve the "green" value. I have tried this as well  $data = mysql_query("Select a.number, a.description, a.value, sample.description, sample.value, sample.number from
(select number,description,value from sample) as a, sample where 
a.number = sample.number and sample.description ='Green'")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: 1 Green 100
1 Yellow 1012 Table 101
2 Green 150     is that the result set you are looking for?

Comment: or are you only trying to get the Greens in the number set [1,2]?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that thx a alot but it shows blanco fields :(.. however I have done many tests this morning after so much coffee  I think what I am trying to do doesn't make sens. Because if I find the record [1, yellow, 101] based on the condition value "101" then it is impossible to add the content-field [Green] as I wanted, because number[1] matches both [101] and [Green]. 
I tried "OR" but it finds also the record [3 green, 105] which is not good because 3 has no [101] data. I know this is crazy puzzle. So now I want to add another Table which will have a UNIQUE number 1,2 and 3 and that number should correspond to the 1st column of the table sample only sample has duplicate of 1's 2' and 3's etc. If I do that would be possible to have a workable condition, where I can display data in one row or list as the following ==> 1, yellow, 101, and Green, 100. I hate to give up :(